# Where is the object created for a class that extends Pane?

Tags: object, javafx-8

I am new to JavaFX. If u look at the attached code, you will see, we are not creating object explicitly while doing property binding; i.e. we see:

**widthProperty.subtract(10);**

[image]

As far as I can understand "this" is used here. But how? 
Will it be a LinePane type object or a Pane type object?

Bye.

Comment: Don't paste images, paste the code. Also, everytime you call `new` you are creating an object. When you have done multiple times in the example.

Comment: What do you man "or a Pane" type. An object of type `LinePane` is a `LinePane` and a `Pane` (as well as a `Region`, `Parent`, `Node` and `Object`). That's how inheritance works. `LinePane` inherits all members of `Pane`; It's "built on top of" `Pane`. The `Pane` part is built first; there'e an implicit `super()` (= superclass constructor) call at the start of the constructor.

Comment: Thank you. I was a little unsure about the implicit super().

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, there is an implicit super call to Pane (the super class). That's why there is implicit "this" while binding. Thanks for the comment (it cleared).